# IHttpActionResult won't return JSON object

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I'm trying to return a JSON result to my client using IHttpActionResult.

My .Net code, looks like this:

```
[AllowAnonymous, HttpPost, Route("")]
public IHttpActionResult Login(LoginRequest login)
{
    if (login == null)
        return BadRequest("No Data Provided");

    var loginResponse = CheckUser(login.Username, login.Password);
    if(loginResponse != null)
    {
        return Ok(new
        {
            message = "Login Success",
            token = JwtManager.GenerateToken(login.Username, loginResponse.Roles),
            success = true
        });
    }
    return Ok( new
    {
        message = "Invalid Username/Password",
        success = false
    });
}
```

This doesn't work though, as I never seem to see the JSON on the response after my JavaScript fetch:

```
const fetchData = ( {method="GET", URL, data={}} ) => {
  console.log("Calling FetchData with URL " + URL);

  var header = {       
    'Content-Type': "application/json",          
  }

  // If we have a bearer token, add it to the header.
  if(typeof window.sessionStorage.accessToken != 'undefined')
  {
    header['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + window.sessionStorage.accessToken
  }

  var config = {
    method: method,
    headers: header
  };

  // I think this adds the data payload to the body, unless it's a get. Not sure what happens with a get.
  if(method !== "GET") {
    config = Object.assign({}, config, {body: JSON.stringify(data)});
  }

  // Use the browser api, fetch, to make the call.
  return fetch(URL, config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response.body);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(function (e) { 
        console.log("An error has occured while calling the API. " + e); 
      });
}
```

There is no JSON available in the body.
How do I get aresult back to my client to parse? response.body doesn't have the json object.

The console.log shows:
[image]

While the request/response shows:
[image]

Using striped's advice: console.log(response.json())

[image]

I see the message there. It seems to be in the wrong place. Shouldn't it be in the body?

Comment: You console.log response, what does it give ?

Comment: Can you debug and can you look at the request/response in the browser dev tools?

Comment: @Crowcoder - added Screen Shot.

Comment: @Striped - Added Screenshot.

Comment: Try to `console.log(response.json())`.

Comment: Progress, @Striped - added to question.

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch works like this

> Body methods
>
> Each of the methods to access the response body returns a Promise that
>   will be resolved when the associated data type is ready.
>
> text() - yields the response text as String
>
> json() - yields the result of JSON.parse(responseText)
>
> blob() - yields a Blob
>
> arrayBuffer() - yields an ArrayBuffer
>
> formData() - yields FormData that can be forwarded to another request

I think you need to

```
return fetch(URL, config)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(e => console.log("An error has occured while calling the API. " + e));
```

doc here: https://github.github.io/fetch/

Answer (score -1):

Your are making a GET request but your controller method is expecting a POST request.

Comment: But the Request Header shows: Access-Control-Request-Method:POST - The method defaults to GET, but I'm sending a POST.

Comment: Does your request end up on your Login method when debugging?